# JSON Attribute response is unidentified

Tags: jquery, json

This is getting me crazy...

```
var _my_obj = my_function(); // Connects to a server and gets data formatted as JSON.

console.log(_my_obj); // Shows me the Object and all its attributes.

console.log(_my_obj.count); // Shows me "unidentified". And I am sure "count " attribute exists.
```

Object

```
   count: 10
    responseJSON: {status: "ok", count: 10, count_total: 12528, pages: 1253, posts: Array(10), …}
    _models_total: 12528
```

Comment: Show us the JSON/object you have

Comment: Object is too Long to paste here.

Comment: @RaffaeleColleo It's anybodys guess without the object, no need to add the whole object if it's large, only add relevant part of it. Create [mcve] or we can't help you.

Comment: Typo. `_my_obj` != `_myobj`

Comment: Already Updated

Comment: Then we need to see the object. This question is unanswerable without it.

Answer (score 0):

The first console.log takes the variable _my_obj as parameter while the second one takes the undeclared variable _myobj. Is the second variable declared somewhere else?

Comment: @RaffaeleColleo could you try to use `Object.keys(_my_obj).length` instead?

Comment: Object.keys(_my_obj).length == 16

Comment: Object.keys(_my_obj).length == 16 when is actually bigger. Should be == to 23